# Vuetify expansion panel validation

Tags: validation, vuetify.js, panel, expand

Is there any way to validate the data of a panel in the submit of a form that contains a multiple expand-panel that one of it´s panels has not been opened?
If this panel does not open, it´s html code is not generated and consequently it´s not validated but, it´s posible force it´s generation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: prop eager of v-expansion-panel-content

Answer (score 0):

Use props **eager** for all **v-expansion-panel-content** where you want to generate HTML and validate conntrols

```
<v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-header class="grey lighten-4">
         </v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content eager> </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```